# Ideal way to start 'Database Server' in PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL version : 11.2
OS : RHEL 7.5

I am new to PostgreSQL. 
I would like to know which is the ideal way to start 'Database server' . In Oracle world, we call this starting the **instance**.

Should I be using Option A or Option B ?

Option A. As root user , run

```
# systemctl start postgresql-11
```

Option B. As postgres user, run

```
$ postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/11/data
```

NB: For Option B, PostgreSQL 11's official doc mentions a different directory (/usr/local/pgsql/data) as shown below . Maybe the doc not updated.

```
$ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/server-start.html

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer option A.

Using `systemctl` ensures the service is properly (re)started when the computer is (re)started.

As far as the location of the data directory is concerned: the manual shows some defaults. The actual location of the data directory is essentially driven by the packager that built the RPM (or whatever package the OS uses) and the standards the distribution expects or uses. You could also put it under `/databasedata/postgres/pg11/data` if you want, or `/very/important/data/postgres`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Option B, because that is the recommended way to restart the PostgreSQL instance.

As you mentioned, in Oracle we have different ways of stopping and starting instance, even in PostgreSQL we have the same, just check pg_ctl --help

you will get different options to stop the database.

and regarding, /usr/local/pgsql/data, that was just a directory where database files installed, you can install any location you want when doing initdb.

I hope it helps.